# VHDL constant used in Verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I have defined a VHDL constant, which I use as a switch inside a "generate" statement to whether generate a portion of the code or skip it.
I have a Verilog module in the same top level, and I would like to do something similar.
I want to use the VHDL constant in Verilog's "ifdef" statement, to either instantiate or skip the Verilog module.
Is there any tricks that I can play to achieve this? Since I know that VHDL constants cannot be used in Verilog "ifdef" statements.

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Answer (score 2):

The `` `ifdef `` would mean you need to decide when and if to set various `` `define MY_MACRO_DEF `` and can pollute your global name space and is compiling order dependent.

Instead, use Verilog's `generate`, introduced in IEEE Std 1364-2001. It is similar to VHDLs approach to generate. Here is an example:

```
module my_module #(parameter PARAM_VALUE=0) ( /* ports */ );
  generate
    if (PARAM_VALUE==1) begin
     ThisModule subinst ( .* );
    else begin
      ThatMoudle subinst ( .* );
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule

module top;
  /* nets */
  genvar gvar_i;
  generate
    for (gvar_i = 0; gvar_i<2; gvar_i=gvar_i+1) begin
      my_module #(.PARAM_VALUE(gvar_i)) inst ( .* );
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

- IEEE Std 1364-2001 § 12.1.3 *Generated instantiation*
- IEEE Std 1364-2005 § 12.4 *Generate constructs*
- [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) (SystemVerilog) § 27. *Generate constructs*